# how to search in a list generated from database using mysql+php

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the following php+mysql code to generate a list of check boxes which are having names of employees and their employee ID as value of that particular check box.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_qry))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='emply[]' 
value='91".$row['empid']."'>".$row['fname']." ".$row['lname'];
echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

with this code segment, I'm getting list of employees, now I want a search box above this list for search through the generated list, so I can easily select particular employee.
Help me with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the MySQLi statement `LIKE '%$mySearchString%'` or for a live search look at a **jquery filter search** plugin.

Comment: Well. No one had read totally the Rahul's question... check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to solve this at client-side, you need a JS solution.

- Just substitite the array example by the result set from BD.

  ```
  <script>
    // the function searches in elements with class 'class_searh' the string 'string_searh'
    function search(class_searh, string_searh) {

      //get elements
      var class_searh_elements = document.getElementsByClassName(class_searh);
      //get string
      var string = string_searh.toString();

      //loop for each element
      for (var i = 0; class_searh_elements.length > i; i++) {

        //get the data on child element on 'class_searh_elements'
        var text_data = class_searh_elements[i].childNodes[0].data;

        //if maches add the class wich hides the element
        if (text_data.search(string) < 0) {
          class_searh_elements[i].classList.add('hidden');
          //if don't maches remove the class wich hides the element
        } else {
          class_searh_elements[i].classList.remove('hidden');
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

  <!--class that hides -->
  <style>
    .hidden {   display: none;   }
  </style>

  <?php
  //array example
  $run_qry = [

    ['empid' => 1, 'fname' => 'john', 'lname' => 'john'],
    ['empid' => 2, 'fname' => 'mary', 'lname' => 'anne'],
    ['empid' => 3, 'fname' => 'mc', 'lname' => 'donalds'],
  ];

  echo "<input type='text' name='string_seach' id='string_search' value='' onkeydown='search(\"elements_class\",this.value)' /> <hr>";

  foreach ($run_qry as $row) {
    echo "<label class='elements_class'>" . $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "<input  type='checkbox' name='emply[]' value='91" . $row['empid'] . "' /><br></label>";
  }
  ```

  ?>

Comment: @Rahul Teja, did you try that ?